# Blender DAE Rejected by Google Earth

Tags: export, collada

I have been unsuccessful at exporting models to Collada (.dae) for importing to Google Earth. Even the default cube doesn't export in a way that Google Earth can read it.

No matter what model I try to export I get an error in Google Earth that says:

> Warning: COLLADA Primitive type [polylist] is not supported, and will not be drawn.

I've tried triangulating the default cube, but I always get the same error.

I am using the latest official build of Blender with Google Earth version 7.1.2.2019

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Sounds like Blender exports as polylist even if it's a triangle. You could check the export code and try to change it.

Comment: Would you consider that to be a bug that I should log?

Comment: no, it's a valid export. It's rather a shortcoming of google earth that it doesn't support all Collada features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem. The solution was changing `<polylist>` to `<triangles>` in source as **CODEmanX** suggested.